# Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.csv. Please find packages

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have 3 dataframe and I want to load then into spark, so I loaded the 3 files saved them into df and comined them to one dataframe. When I apply spark to the dataframe
I get this error "Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.csv. Please find packages" Do I need to download org.apache.spark.csv in my local file then load it ?

```
dfA = pd.read_excel("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dfA.xlsx",  names=['','Name', 'Prod_No','Category','URL','Description']) 

dfB = pd.read_excel("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dfB.xlsx", names=['','Name', 'Prod_No','Category','URL','Description']) 

dfC = pd.read_excel("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/dfC.xlsx", names=['','Name', 'Prod_No','Category','URL','Description']) 

#delete index column 
dfA = df_7news.drop([''], axis=1)
dfB = df_theAge.drop([''], axis=1)
dfC =df_thenewDaily.drop([''], axis=1)
# reset index and merge dataframe and delete row with replay data
df = pd.concat([dfA,dfB,dfC],ignore_index=True)
df = df[df.Article.str.contains("Replay") == False]

 

data = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").option("inferSchema", "True").load(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the full format, just use `spark.read.format("csv")`

You can even just use `spark.read.csv(path)`